# I get TypeError: (intermediate value).sendProducts is not a function but it is, for some reason it says that for the first line when it is call

Tags: javascript, node.js, mern

I keep getting the type error sendPurchaseEmail is not a function. And this is the code

```
const { User } = require("./models/people");
const catchAsync = require("./utils/catchasync");
const { Cart } = require("../models/cart");
const Profile = require("./../models/profile");
const Purchase = require("./../models/purchaseItems");
const factory = require("./handlerFactory");
const Email = require("./../utils/email");
const Product = require("./../models/product");
const _ = require("lodash");

const Email = require("./utils/email");

module.exports.getCheckoutSession = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => 
{
const userId = req.body.id;
const domainUrl = process.env.WEB_APP_URL;
const customer_email = req.body.email;
const line_items = req.body.cartItems;



if (userId) {
const Items = await Cart.find({ user: userId });
//Product Name
const allProductName = Items.map((item) => {
  return item.product.name;
});
//Product Id
const allProductId = Items.map((item) => {
  return item.product._id;
});
const total_amount = Items.map((item) => item.count * 
 item.price).reduce(
  (a, b) => a + b,
  0
);


  //Create checkout session
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  payment_method_types: ["card"],

  success_url: `${domainUrl}/success`,
  cancel_url: `${domainUrl}/canceled`,
  mode: "payment",
  shipping_address_collection: {
    allowed_countries: ["US", "CA"],
  },
  shipping_options: [
    {
      shipping_rate_data: {
        type: "fixed_amount",
        fixed_amount: {
          amount: 900,
          currency: "usd",
        },
        display_name: "Regular shipping",
        // Delivers between 5-7 business days
        delivery_estimate: {
          minimum: {
            unit: "business_day",
            value: 5,
          },
          maximum: {
            unit: "business_day",
            value: 10,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  allow_promotion_codes: true,
  //client code end
  // customer_email: req.body.email,
  customer_email: customer_email,
  client_reference_id: allProductId.join(" "),

  // line_items: [
  //   {
  //     price_data: {
  //       currency: "usd",
  //       product_data: {
  //         name: allProductName.join(" "),
  //         images: [
  //           `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/img/products/${
  //             Items[0].product.photo
  //           }`,
   line_items: Items.map((item) => {
     return {
      price_data: {
        currency: "usd",
        product_data: {
          name: item.product.name,
        },

        unit_amount: item.product.price * 100,
      },
      description: item.product.description,
      quantity: item.count,

    };
   }),
  });


return res.status(200).json({
  status: "success",
  session,
});
} else {


const allProductName = req.body.cartItems.map((item) => {
  return item.name;
});
//Create checkout session
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  payment_method_types: ["card"],

  success_url: `${domainUrl}/success`,
  cancel_url: `${domainUrl}/canceled`,
  mode: "payment",
  //Client code added
  // Adding the shipping prices
  shipping_address_collection: {
    allowed_countries: ["US", "CA"],
  },
  shipping_options: [
    {
      shipping_rate_data: {
        type: "fixed_amount",
        fixed_amount: {
          amount: 900,
          currency: "usd",
        },
        display_name: "Regular shipping",
        // Delivers between 5-10 business days
        delivery_estimate: {
          minimum: {
            unit: "business_day",
            value: 5,
          },
          maximum: {
            unit: "business_day",
            value: 10,
          },
        },
      },
    },
   ],
   allow_promotion_codes: true,
   customer_email: customer_email,
    line_items: line_items.map((item) => {
    return {
      price_data: {
        currency: "usd",
        product_data: {
          name: item.name,
        },

        unit_amount: item.price * 100,
      },
      description: item.description,
      quantity: item.quantity,
      //tax_rates: [process.env.TAX_ID],
    };
  }),
  });


req.body.total+(session.total_details.amount_shipping/100));


 return res.status(200).json({
  status: "success",
  session,
 });
 }
});


const createPurchaseCheckout = async (
  session,
  fullName,
  total,
  currency,
  state,
  custEmail,
) => {
  try {
      const userExist = (await User.findOne({ email: custEmail }));
      if (userExist) {
      const user_Id = (await User.findOne({ email: custEmail }))._id;
      const userProfile = _.pick(session.shipping.address, [
        "line1",
        "line2",
        "city",
        "state",
        "postal_code",
        "country",
      ]);
      userProfile["user"] = user_Id;
      let profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: user_Id });
      if (profile){
        await Profile.updateOne({ user: user_Id }, userProfile);
      } else {
        profile = new Profile(userProfile);
        await profile.save();
      }

      const productStr = await session.client_reference_id;

      if(productStr) {

        const product = productStr.split(" ");
        const user = await User.findOne({ email: custEmail });
        const userId = user._id;
     
        const guestAmount = session.amount_total/100;
        const price = guestAmount;
        await Purchase.create({ product, user: userId, price });
        await Cart.deleteMany({ user: userId });
  
        await new Email(
          user,
          fullName,
          total,
          currency,
          state).sendPurchaseEmail();
    
        await new Email(
          user,
          fullName,
          total,
          currency,
          process.env.INFO
        ).sendProducts();
      }

      else if (!productStr) {
        let user = {
          email: custEmail,
        };
        await new Email(user,
          fullName,
          total,
          currency,
          state).sendPurchaseEmail();
        await new Email(
          user,
          fullName,
          total,
          currency,
          process.env.INFO
      ).sendProducts();
      }

    } else {
     
      let user = {
        email: custEmail,
      };
      await new Email(user,
        fullName,
        total,
        currency,
        state).sendPurchaseEmail();
      await new Email(
        user,
        fullName,
        total,
        currency,
        process.env.INFO
      ).sendProducts();
    }
  } catch (err) {return;}
};
module.exports.webhookCheckout = async (req, res, next) 
=> {
const signature = req.headers["stripe-signature"];

let event;
try {
event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
  req.body,
  signature,
  process.env.SECRET
);
} catch (err) {
return res.status(400).send(`Webhook error: 
${err.message}`);
}


if (event.type === "checkout.session.completed") {
const cust = event.data.object;
const custId = event.data.object.id;



const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(
  custId, {
  expand: ['line_items.data.price.product']
});

    const items = session['line_items']['data'];

    const total = session.amount_total/100;
    const currency = session.currency;




 const whatWasOrdered = items.map((item) => {
  return `${item.quantity} of the 
  ${item.price.product.name}`
  });



    const discount = items.map((item) => {
      return item.amount_discount/100
    });






  const fullName = cust.customer_details.name;
  const shipping = cust.shipping.address;
  const custEmail = cust.customer_email;

  createPurchaseCheckout(
  event.data.object,
  fullName,
  total,
  currency,
  whatWasOrdered,
  discount,
  // quantity,
  shipping.city,
  shipping.country,
  shipping.line1,
  shipping.line2,
  shipping.postal_code,
  shipping.state,
  custEmail,
);

}



res.status(200).json({ received: true });
};
```

and this is the email file that the function is coming from, I checked the spelling and it is correct

```
module.exports = class Email {
constructor(
user,
total,
currency,
url,
postal_code = "",
state = "",
// trying to add the customer email

custEmail = ""
// adding firstName now which is actually the fullName

) {

this.firstName = fullName === undefined ? "" : fullName.split(" ")[0];
this.fullName = fullName === undefined ? "" : fullName.split("  ");
this.user = user.email;
this.country = country;
this.custEmail = custEmail;
this.from = `${process.env.FROM}`;
this.total=total,
this.currency=currency,
}

newTransport() {
if (process.env.ENV === "production") {
  return nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "MailService",
    auth: {
      user: "bdna",
      pass: "passssss",
    },
  });
}
return nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "somekode",
  port: "blach blah",
  auth: {
    user: "someKoddealso",
    pass: "balhd blach",
  },
  });
}


  async send(template, subject) {
  const html = pug.renderFile(`${__dirname}/views/email/${template}.pug`, {
  firstName: this.firstName,
  fullName: this.fullName,
  total: this.total,
  currency: this.currency,
  custEmail: this.custEmail,
  user: this.user,
  subject,
});

const mailOptions = {
  from: this.from,
  to: this.to,
  subject,
  html,
  text: htmlToText.fromString(html),
};

await this.newTransport().sendMail(mailOptions);
}

 async sendPurchaseEmail() {
await this.send("PurchaseSuccess", "Thank you");
}

 async sendProducts() {
 await this.send("SendProducts", "Another Order Has been Made");
 }
};

module.exports = class SendEmail {
constructor(
  email,
  resetUrl,
  // custEmail = ""
  // adding firstName now which is actually the fullName

) {
  this.email = email,
  this.to = email;
  // this.custEmail = custEmail;
  this.from = `${process.env.FROM}`;
  this.famDiscount = `${process.env.FAM}`,
  this.resetUrl = resetUrl
}

//newtransport start...
if (process.env.ENV === "production") {
  return nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "MailService",
    auth: {
      user: "bdna",
      pass: "passssss",
    },
  });
}
return nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "somekode",
  port: "blach blah",
  auth: {
    user: "someKoddealso",
    pass: "balhd blach",
  },
  });
}
//newtransport end...

// Send the actual email start
async send(template, subject) {
  // 1) Render HTML based on a pug template
  const html = pug.renderFile(`${__dirname}/../views/email/${template}.pug`, {
    firstName: this.firstName,
    fullName: this.fullName,
    custEmail: this.custEmail,
    user: this.user,
    resetUrl: this.resetUrl,
    famDiscount: this.famDiscount,
    activateLink: this.activateLink,
    subject,
  });

  const message = {
    from: `${process.env.FROM}`,
    to: this.to,
    subject,
    html,
    text: htmlToText.fromString(html),
  };

  // 3) Create a transport and send email
  await this.newTransport().sendMail(message);
}
// Send the actual email end
async sendPasswordReset() {
  await this.send("PasswordReset", "RESET PASSWORD");
}
async activateEmail() {
  await this.send("Activate", "Use the Link to activate 
your account");
}
};
```

The issue is coming from the first sendPurchaseEmail. Stating that it is not a function, I checked but I do not know what else to do? Please help

Comment: what did you check and how did you check it?

Comment: I ran the code, and the error comes out on the back end. I added the code if(product) { …. 

I added it to factor in those people whose have an account but are not logged in. But before i added that if statement in. It worked except for when people have an account but are not logged in. Idk if it is to many if statements or what. If you need more info. Just let me know